# What are the possible parameters for CompilerParameters.CompilerOptions

Tags: c#, codedom

I am trying to find all the possible parameters that can be used with CompilerParameters.CompilerOptions with explanation. I cant find it on google, not even at MSDN. I am using it with CPPCodeProvider. Can anyone with the knowledge please help me with the issue. I have provided the example below, but cant understand what these parameters do.

```
string options = "/optimize+ /platform:x86 /target:winexe /unsafe";
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the compiler options with brief descriptions on MSDN:

[C# Compiler Options Listed Alphabetically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0.aspx)

Here are the descriptions for the ones in your question:

> **/optimize**
>
> Enables/disables optimizations.
>
> **/platform**
>
> Limits which platforms this code can run on:
> x86, Itanium, x64, anycpu, or anycpu32bitpreferred. The default is anycpu.
>
> **/target**
>
> Specifies the format of the output file by using one of four options:
> /target:appcontainerexe, /target:exe, /target:library, /target:module, /target:winexe, /target:winmdobj
>
> **/unsafe**
>
> Allows unsafe code.

Comment: Exactly :D I spent hours searching for it, but cant find :(

Comment: My search phrase on goolge was "c# compiler arguments". It's mostly a matter of search phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the documentation you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: at [MSDN - C# Compiler Options Listed Alphabetically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0.aspx)

- **`/optimize`**: Enables/disables optimizations.
- **`/platform`**: Limits which platforms this code can run on: x86, Itanium, x64, anycpu, or anycpu32bitpreferred. The default is anycpu.
- **`/target`**: Specifies the format of the output file by using one of four options:/target:appcontainerexe, /target:exe, /target:library, /target:module, /target:winexe, /target:winmdobj.
- **`/unsafe`**: Allows unsafe code.